# Open Google Maps App in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6-maps

I would like to open Google Map App in iOS 6 programmatically.
I tried to open the maps in by passing url -  maps.....
but it is still opening in the Safari

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
```

reference:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Answer (score 0):

try this

The domain must be maps.apple.com.

A parameter cannot be q=* if the value is a URL (so KML is not picked up).
The parameters cannot include view=text or dirflg=r.

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1
```